# Installing OpenX (Revive AdServer) with remote DB

Tags: php, mysql, openx

Dear openx experts out there,

I'm new to PHP and also Revive AdServer (OpenX).

I successfully installed a Revive server using MySql, in a condition where both instances hosted in the same hardware.

My question is, how can I install the Revive server in a different hardware using MySql that hosted in another hardware?

The error on Revive installation wizard is mentioned that MySql not present, and some how I have to checked on php.ini file.

Has anybody tried this attempt before and succeeded, please do drop by and advice me.

Thanks,
Bromo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revive Ad Server Installation using Remote MySQL :

While Installation Wizard , enter IP Address of your Remote MySQL Server instead of "localhost"

Also Grant Privileges to that mysql user .

If you trying to setup a cluster for openx or revive adserver

Reference:

http://www.sherin.co.in/openxcluster121 &
http://www.sherin.co.in/openxhandbook

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that the server you are installing Revive Adserver on (not the database server) does not have the required MySQL libraries installed, so PHP does not have MySQL support present. As a result, your PHP server cannot "talk" to a MySQL server.

You will need to (or ask your system administrator to) update the web server that has PHP installed on it, onto which you are attempting to install Revive Adserver, so that the PHP installation has support for talking to MySQL databases.

Once this is done, you should be able to install Revive Adserver just fine, and point it at the remote MySQL server that you want to use.